# Large integer modulo division is not very convincing

Tags: python, integer, modulo

Look at these:

```
>>>from mpmath import mp

>>> 20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921 % 2623617082180073274358906876623916797788160
291280009243618888211558641
>>> 20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921 % 5247234164360146548717813753247833595576320
291280009243618888211558641 <<<HOW CAN THIS BE THE SAME ANSWER AS ABOVE?
>>> mp.fdiv(20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921, 5247234164360146548717813753247833595576320)
mpf('4.00000000000000005551115123125782779)
>>> mp.fdiv(20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921, 2623617082180073274358906876623916797788160)
mpf('8.00000000000000011102230246251565558)
```

I am trying to write a program that returns true if a large number is prime.
As you probably already know, python has its limits. Not just with floating point numbers but also with large numbers above a decillion. If my Python 3.7 (64-bit) can support large integers up to:

```
import sys
int(sys.float_info.max)
179769313486231570814527423731704356798070567525844996598917476803157260780028538760589558632766878171540458953514382464234321326889464182768467546703537516986049910576551282076245490090389328944075868508455133942304583236903222948165808559332123348274797826204144723168738177180919299881250404026184124858368
```

...then why can I not do a simple modulo on the numbers above and not get inconsistencies? Can anyone refer me to some other tool to help me or is there something I'm just missing?

Comment: I'm getting the exact same results in Clojure using BigIntegers. I'm too tired to consider the maths, but the results you're getting seem legitimate. The first two do in fact result in the same answer.

Comment: right...but look at the mpmath divisions....
They are 4.00000000000000then5551115123125782779
I guess it rounds it to a 4 or what? If it does, then the modulo actually gives a wrong answer.

Comment: Python appears to be correct here.  What makes you think it isn't?

Comment: The two mp.fdiv() show different floating point answers. Since the floating point decimal answers are different, the remainder of the modulo on the two shouldn't be the same. I'm guessing Python is rounding it because the zeros go above 15-16 places from the decimal point.

Comment: Again, I'm way too tired to consider math in any depth right now, but I can replicate your results exactly in my Clojure REPL. If there is something wrong here, it's also wrong in the JVM/Clojure number module.

Comment: @InfinityLoop: The `fdiv()` is giving different floating point values because the divisors are different — specifically, 5247...6320 is two times 2623...8160, so 2098...3921 / 5247...6320 should have a mantissa that is half the mantissa of 2098...3921 / 2623...8160, which it does.

Comment: 20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921 is supposedly a prime number. For some reason Python modulo returns more than two '0's from 1 to 20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921.

Comment: @InfinityLoop: [WolframAlpha thinks it's prime](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=is+20988936657440586486151264256610222593863921+prime), and the calculations in your post give no reason to doubt that.  What are the two 0's that Python is returning?

Comment: I'm sorry guys. I figured out the problem I was having. Python was turning the number into scientific notation and then checking it as that. I upped the mp.dps() higher and now I get the correct results. Someone can delete this post if they want.

Comment: As it has received no answers, you are able to delete your own question - if that suits.